# PHP Image Upload Not Working - No Errors

Tags: php, mysqli, upload

I'm not getting any errors when I run this script. It is creating the directories needed, but the image is not being moved or uploaded. It's not the best code in the world, but I feel like I am on the right track for what I need. I know I still need to escape the user input and limit file types to images only on the server side.

Could anyone tell me/show me how to improve this code?

```
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings/global.php');
 session_start();
 $fName = $_POST['first_name'];
 $lName = $_POST['last_name'];
 $dob = $_POST['dob'];
 $dod = $_POST['dod'];
 $born = $_POST['born'];
 $image = $_FILES['image'];
 $about = $_POST['about'];
 $started = $_POST['started'];
 $company = $_POST['company'];

 $name = $lName.$fName;
 $name1 = substr($name, 0, 1); 
 $name2 = substr($name, 0, 2); 
 $name3 = substr($name, 0, 3); 
 $name4 = substr($name, 0, 4); 

  $imagePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/fallenIcons/".$name1."/".$name2."/".$name3."/".$name4."/".$name."/";

  $imageStorePath = "http://example.com/images/fallenIcons/".$name1."/".$name2."/".$name3."/".$name4."/".$name."/";


 if (!file_exists($imagePath)) {
    mkdir($imagePath, 0777, true);
}

 $filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
 $extension = end(explode(".", $filename));
 $newfilename = $name .".".$extension;

 $image = $imageStorePath.$newfilename;

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'tmp_name' ], $imageStorePath.$newfilename);

 $mysqli=mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,'fallenPEVORecords');
 $query = "INSERT INTO fallenPEVOEntries (first_name,last_name,date_of_birth,date_of_death,born_in,main_image,pevo_details,year_started,worked_for,approved) 
                              VALUES 
                             ('$fName','$lName','$dob','$dod','$born','$image','$about','$started','$company','pending')";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());

 if($result) {
  header('Location: http://example.com/fallen/addFallen.php');
  echo 'true';
 }
 else{
 echo 'false';
 }
```

HTML:

```
<form action="http://example.com/scripts/php/addFallen.php" method="post">
        <ul>
              <li> 
               <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
           <input type="text" size="30"  name="first_name"/>
          </li>
          <li> 
               <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
           <input type="text" size="30"  name="last_name"/>
          </li>
          <li> 
               <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
           <input type="text" size="30"  name="dob" class="datepicker">
          </li>
          <li> 
               <label for="dod">Date of Passing</label>
           <input type="text" size="30"  name="dod" class="datepicker">
          </li>
          <li> 
               <label for="born">Born In [City, State]</label>
           <input type="text" size="30"  name="born"/>
          </li>
          <li> 
               <label for="image">Image</label>
           <input type="file" name="image" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg"/>
          </li>
          <li> 
               <label for="about">About The PEVO</label>
           <textarea name="about" rows="8" cols="45"></textarea>
          </li>
          <li> 
               <label for="started">When did this PEVO start piloting? [Year]</label>
           <input type="text" name="started"  class="date-picker-year">
          </li>
          <li> 
               <label for="company">Company Worked For</label>
           <input type="text" name="company" size="30">
          </li>
                  <li> 
                   <label></label>
           <input type="submit" name="addFallen" value="Submit">
          </li>
          <li>
           <b>ALL SUBMISSIONS MUST BE APPROVED BY AN ADMIT BEFORE THEY APPEAR!</b>
          </li>
        </ul>
         </form>
```

**EDIT**
Just modified how you get your extension

```
<?php 
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/settings/global.php');
 session_start();
 $fName = $_POST['first_name'];
 $lName = $_POST['last_name'];
 $dob = $_POST['dob'];
 $dod = $_POST['dod'];
 $born = $_POST['born'];
 $image = $_FILES['image'];
 $about = $_POST['about'];
 $started = $_POST['started'];
 $company = $_POST['company'];

 $name = $lName.$fName;
 $name1 = substr($name, 0, 1); 
 $name2 = substr($name, 0, 2); 
 $name3 = substr($name, 0, 3); 
 $name4 = substr($name, 0, 4); 

  $imagePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/images/fallenIcons/".$name1."/".$name2."/".$name3."/".$name4."/".$name."/";

  $imageStorePath = "http://example.com/images/fallenIcons/".$name1."/".$name2."/".$name3."/".$name4."/".$name."/";


 if (!file_exists($imagePath)) {
    mkdir($imagePath, 0777, true);
}

 $filename = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
 $extension = pathinfo( $filename );
 $extension = ( isset( $extension[ 'extension' ] ) && trim( $extension[ 'extension' ] ) ? $extension[ 'extension' ] : '' );
 $newfilename = $name .".".$extension;

 $image = $imageStorePath.$newfilename;

 move_uploaded_file($_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'tmp_name' ], $image );

 $mysqli=mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,'fallenPEVORecords');
 $query = "INSERT INTO fallenPEVOEntries (first_name,last_name,date_of_birth,date_of_death,born_in,main_image,pevo_details,year_started,worked_for,approved) 
                              VALUES 
                             ('$fName','$lName','$dob','$dod','$born','$image','$about','$started','$company','pending')";
 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());

 if($result) {
  header('Location: http://example.com/fallen/addFallen.php');
  echo 'true';
 }
 else{
 echo 'false';
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First argument in move_uploaded_file() is the temp file of the uploaded file, here you are giving another thing to it

```
move_uploaded_file($image, $imagePath.$newfilename);
```

Should be

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'tmp_name' ], $imagePath.$newfilename);
```

Comment: changed it but still didn't move the file.

Comment: In your form, are you sure you are  having `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute?

Comment: I'll post my html :) I should have done that from the start.

Comment: Now your form is not having it...it should lie here 
`<form action="http://example.com/scripts/php/addFallen.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: That fixed it. Other than escaping user input, got any suggestions to improve this script?

Comment: Okay, your codes are good. Just edited and modified how file extension is gotten

Comment: Thanks :) I haven't worked with file uploading too much so I was hoping I wasn't doing too bad lol